# Failed to install HAXM during Android Studio installation

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I'm trying to install Android Studio, but it's showing this error.
Is there a solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that helps (apologies if not), but you might try to just use Android Studio anyway. Seems like the thing that's failing is just HAXM. It's not required to use Android Studio. It's required for the emulator to work faster. So if you don't intend to use the emulator or if the slower speed is acceptable to you then you should be able to still use Android Studio.

Comment: Can't you install it separately?

Comment: Follow along this guideline I wrote and you will be fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932346/facing-android-studio-emulator-error-with-amd-cpu-2021

Comment: It only works with the Intel system.

Comment: did you enable virtualization in bios? i think you use amd cpu.

Answer (score 39):

As @Marcin Koziński said in Intel, HAXM requires only to run the Emulator faster. Still, if you want to install HAXM, follow the steps.

1. Restart your PC and go to BIOS
2. In advanced option, Enable Virtualization and save exit
3. After Windows restarted, go to the SDK path of your Android Studio
4. Find this path `\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`
5. Run `intelhaxm-android.exe` executable

Now, this would install HAXM software in your system. Note that your system must have Intel CPU, not AMD

Comment: This solution works for me! I enable Virtualization from BIOS Security options in my Lenovo and then installed HAXM from android studio succesfully!!

Comment: For windows 11, you need to disable `Core Isolation` to successfully install  HAXM,
otherwise it just fails

Answer (score 21):

Ignore this error on Android Studio installation and go to the Intel website, download the HAXM installer that they provide (instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio).

Here's the link:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

and the direct link:
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.6.1

Comment: The project has been discontinued since Jan 28, 2023.

Answer (score 13):

Try this :

Go to Control Panel → Program and Feature. Click on Turn Window Features on and off. Uncheck Hyper-V option and restart your system.

Now you should install HAXM with no error

Comment: When i launch android studio its crash i am  Unchecked Hyper-V option and restart my system.again installed.Still showing these issues.How to over come these.

Comment: Here is a link that solved my issue. The steps above were helpful but I was getting different options from the Control Panel>

https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004254383?utm_campaign=disableHyperV&utm_content=disableHyperV&utm_medium=disableHyperV&utm_source=disableHyperV&utm_term=disableHyperV

Comment: For windows 11, you need to disable Core Isolation to successfully install HAXM, otherwise it just fails

Answer (score 7):

Enable virtualization in your bios ( found under the cpu performance ) …then disable hypervisor and also unchecked virtual machine platform ( mostly on win 10 and win 11)

Restart your machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Turning off "Virtual Machine Platform" was the solution for me.

Comment: Unchecking virtual machine platform solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue, however i have tried below steps which worked for me.

1. Instead of installing HAXM from android studio, download it from
   here [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm)
2. From - Downloads section, you can download MAC or WINDOWS release.
3. Install it from IntelHaxm-android file

**Note - Same kind of steps we can follow for Mac.**

Answer (score 2):

I disabled tamper protection and core isolation in windows defender and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to android studio SDK Manager select SDK tools and search for Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM Installer) and install it. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 10, then, be sure to disable "Windows Defender Credential Guard".

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in the Window features on or off, I uncheck both the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" and "Virtual Machine Platform". After restart, the Android Studio, SDK Manager, Android SDK, SDK Tools, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator 7.6.5 can then successfully be installed. Just uncheck the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is not enough. My Android Studio is 4.1.3 and my Windows 10 OS build is 19041.867

Comment: Turning off "Virtual Machine Platform" was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel → Program and Feature. Click on Turn Windows Features on and off. Uncheck Hyper-V and Windows Sandbox option and restart your system.

Answer (score 1):

I enabled Virtualization in my BIOS and the installation worked, i have intel I5 CPU

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Virtualization in BIOS solved the issue for me. If you have an Intel processor, you need to enable VMX in the CPU configuration file. Here is an detailed article with the steps (for asus motherboards). https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1043786/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a perfect [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932346/facing-android-studio-emulator-error-with-amd-cpu-2021) for that. The key is to download the `HAXM` driver but don't close the Android installation window after it's downloaded. You need to find it's path and run the installer .bat through `Powershell` or `CMD`. Simply follow along the mentioned guideline I wrote and you will be finde. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a **macbook pro laptop**, **make sure to reboot to windows without pressing the option key for boot selection**. As this will disable virtualization .

*To soft reboot to windows*

Soft reboot via the Apple menu i.e. top left Apple icon => restart. During bootup select Windows/Bootcamp (via the option key). My Windows was Bitlocker encrypted, so I entered the disk password, booted to Windows, entered Windows password, landed on Windows 10 desktop. This time Hyper-V was present and functional!

**if the error still persists. Ignore the Android Studio installation error**

*Disable the Hyper-V Manager*

Hyper-V is another Virtualisation env. just like Intel HAXM.
You cannot use both at the same time. Hence, It is necessary to Disable Hyper-V.

You can follow these steps to disable Hyper-V
[image]

Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off

From the window disable Hyper-V options

Reboot your machine

*or on cmd prompt with admin priveledges:*

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Go to the Intel website, download the HAXM installer that they provide (instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio).

Here's the link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

and the direct link: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.6.1

Comment: For windows 11, you need to disable Core Isolation to successfully install HAXM, otherwise it just fails

Answer (score 1):

1. Open BIOS setting of your PC/Laptop.
2. Goto Advance -> Device Configuation.
3. Enable **VTx(Virtualization Technology)**.

and Try to install HAXM.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

IF u have AMD CPU you have to install Driver for AMD processor(It's in SDK Tools options menu.) then go to C:\Users\YOURNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver and run silent_install.bat.  If it doesn't work try cloning your emulator device instead creating new one. Also, you might have to set SDK root home folder as a new variable.

Comment: for AMD, download Android Canary

Answer (score 0):

when you press +creating virtual device and selcting device on the right side of   it shows you  HAXM installation or something ,you can check there.

Comment: Hi and welcome! When answer a question making reference to the UI it would be a good idea to attach a screenshot, otherwise is hard to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding here the official Release Notes of the HAXM.

This is not a solution answer but it will complete the solutions already mentioned in terms of requirements and known issues:

> **Prerequisites**

> Intel(R) HAXM requires the Android SDK to be installed
> (version 17 or higher). For best performance, using SDK version 20 or
> higher is recommended.
>
> System Requirements
> ---------------------------- Hardware Requirements:
>
> - Intel(R) processor with support for VT-x, EM64T, and Execute Disable Bit
> - At least 1GB of available RAM
>
> Supported Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows* 10 (64-bit)
> - Windows* 8.1 (64-bit)
> - Windows* 8 (64-bit)
> - Windows* 7 (64-bit)
> - macOS* 10.12, 10.13, 10.14
>
> **Note:**
>
> - Test was NOT conducted on Windows* XP since Microsoft* will not offer support for this version.
> - Test was NOT conducted on 32-bit Windows since Android Emulator only supports 64-bit Windows.
>
> **Important:**
>
> 1. Intel HAXM cannot be used on systems without an Intel processor, or an Intel processor lacking the hardware features, described in the
>    "Hardware Requirements" section above. To determine the capabilities
>    of your Intel processor, please visit http://ark.intel.com/
> 2. Intel HAXM can only accelerate Android x86 and x86_64 system images for Android Emulator. These system images as well as Android Emulator
>    can be installed using Android SDK Manager.
>
> **Known Issues:**
>
> - HAXM driver does not support emulating a 64-bit system image on Intel systems based on Core microarchitecture (Core, Core 2 Duo etc.).
>   All systems based on Nehalem and beyond are supported (Core i3, Core
>   i5 and Core i7 machines).
> - QEMU or Android Emulator will fail to launch if the guest RAM size (specified with the -m option for QEMU or -memory for Android
>   Emulator) exceeds 4095MB.
> - If the guest RAM size (specified with the -memory option for Android Emulator) exceeds 3583MB, Android will either fail to boot or report
>   the total memory as 3.0GB.
> - If DriverVerifier is running on a Windows System on which HAXM is installed BSOD can happen during HAXM uninstall. Check the following
>   link for more information from Microsoft.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448(v=vs.85).aspx
> - On Windows platform using sc query command on command line will show the driver to be in Running state even if VT is disabled in BIOS. The
>   Android SDK gets this information from HAXM driver whether VT is
>   enabled or not and displays it to user when the user starts to emulate
>   a device. The information in the SDK is the most accurate information
>   for the state of the HAXM driver.
> - On Windows 8, 8.1 and 10, it is recommended to disable Hyper-V from Windows Features in order for the HAXM driver to properly function.
> - On Windows, Avast Antivirus may interfere with HAXM and cause Android Emulator or QEMU to run very slowly. A workaround is to
>   uncheck "Use nested virtualization where available" in Avast Settings

Answer (score 0):

Have tried some solutions stated above, sadly it did not work for me.

Just noticed that when I install HAXM it uninstall HAXM after installing, so what I did was after the installation even gets finished (before setting how much RAM to give it) I went to the SDK folder on %appdata% then copied the folder from Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager which can be seen on extras folder then I exit android studio then paste the folder on extras/intel then it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

If you already disabled completely Hyper-V and it's still not working disable also:

Windows Hypervisor Platform

[image]

"The Windows Hypervisor platform is an API that third-party developers can use in order to use Hyper-V."

Ofcourse you're CPU need to be intel based and also you need to turn on Virtualization options in BIOS.

Hope it helps if not I wish you a lot of luck.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is HP x360. I had to enable virtualization in BIOS( use f10)

Then do this step https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105#issuecomment-470296375

if memory integrity is off inside core isolation. Switch it on.
If you get an incompatible driver error when you switch on above feature, then find and uninstall/delete it.
In my case, Tencent's gaming buddy was the driver.
In some systems, the windows feature Hyper-V is not listed. instead, it is "Windows Hypervisor Platform" <- Uncheck this.

These all may take multiple restarts.
Then finally try installing HAXM from android studio.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As [fabio-roveroto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376744/fabio-roveroto) ignore this error because HAXM is used for Android Emulator.

If you want to use Android Emulator you must install HAXM please follow these steps in the below link for fixing the error:

https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003174386?utm_campaign=bgp_product&utm_medium=app_player&utm_source=support

And If you can't find `UEFI Firmware Settings` in the `Advanced options`, please check that your PC BIOS mode is Legacy or UEFI from this [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/ways-to-fix-missing-uefi-firmware-settings/), If your BIOS mode is Legacy

check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23161_01/html/E37044/glsem.html) to convert Legacy to UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM error. Installation failed.

1. Go to **Windows** **feature** on/off(Search) : **UNCHECK** Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform.
2. Go to the **BIOS** setup and turn on the virtualization(Lenovo **Thinkpad**) -> To open the BIOS -> Turn ON the laptop -> Press Power Button for 10 seconds -> Now press the power button again -> Press Enter.
3. After turning on the **virtualization** : save and start the machine again then go to the google search and type **HAXM** **download** -> download the HAXM .exe
4. **Manually** **install** the HAXM downloaded from the website.
5. Go to android studion **SDK** manager -> Install **emulator**.