# Is there how to solve an error of "unable to install intel haxm" on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

1. I tried to open run my program on the Android studio.
   `Error: Unable to install HAXM`
2. I uninstalled the HAXM from the android studio to reinstall.
   `Error: Unable to install Intel HAXM
   Unknown Error
   Please file a bug against Android Studio.`
3. I tried to download another emulator and a new operating system and the error is the same as usual.

[image: It is the response when I tried running/testing the program on the emulator]

Comment: Try to download install intel x86 Emulator Accelerator from [https://www.filecroco.com/download-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/] restart android studio. I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: please refer [I can't install intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm) or [Failed to install HAXM during Android Studio installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795704/failed-to-install-haxm-during-android-studio-installation) .

Comment: @VishalBari the webpage link is not going, it says "page not found"

Comment: Use this :  https://www.filecroco.com/download-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee I apologize but None of those links has solved the issue, I have tried them already.

Comment: @VishalBari I have downloaded and installed but after installation, it redirects me to this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/android and still no change with the android studio

Comment: Did you try to restart your android studio? Or Invalidate your android studio cache and restart option

Comment: invalidate caches and restart right? Yes I did

Comment: Had a similar issue and none of the suggestions worked. Had upgraded the OS, so as a final resort decided to update drivers for it from the official site, completely removed android studio and reinstalled, and everything worked fine. So try if updating your drivers helps as some utility or framework might be missing.