# Android Studio Intel Haxm installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

im trying to run android studio emulator and instal HAXM
and the installation is failed i dont know why i try alot of soultions

i dont have Hyper-V! (uncheked)

SDK is up to date android studio is up to date
in the sdk tools im trying to install the haxm and is shows errors!

[image]

Comment: it's an error with the systm, So add some of your system specs, you window specs, etc

Comment: is your laptop processor Intel or AMD?
If AMD you need to install AMD one available in SDK
if Intel reset your android studio it worked for me

Comment: @Harsh0021
I have laptop with intel
windows 10 Home

Comment: @Vatsalkesarwani 
Intel and windows 10 home

Comment: Enable Hyper - V

Comment: @Harsh0021 when i enable Hyper-V its empty! 
i enable hyper-v and then android studi AVD and try to run emulator and error!

Comment: Check this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32795704/5180017)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the please note that the "Finish" button indicates that the installation completed successfully, 
which means that haxm is not required for android studio basic usage.

**So, If you wish to install haxm**

you should try to follow the instructions found at: 
https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows

as recommended in the error message.
(I've changed the link to the new one)

And if you don't find this guide helpful, 
try to follow the answers for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm)
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795704/failed-to-install-haxm-during-android-studio-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Verify Virtualization Support

1. Open a Command Prompt as an administrator.
2. Type `systeminfo` and press Enter.
3. Scroll down to the "Hyper-V Requirements" section.
4. Ensure that "Virtualization Enabled in Firmware" is set to "Yes"
5. If it's set to "No" you need to enable virtualization in your BIOS settings. Here's how:

   - Restart your laptop.
   - Access the BIOS settings during startup (usually by pressing a key like F2, F12, or Del).
   - Find the virtualization setting (often labeled as "VT-x" or "Virtualization Technology").
   - Enable virtualization and save the BIOS settings.
   - Restart your laptop.

Enable Hyper-V (if necessary)

1. Click the Start button and go to Control Panel.
2. Navigate to Programs > Turn Windows features on or off.
3. Look for the "Hyper-V" or "Virtual Environment" option.
4. If it's unchecked, enable it by clicking the checkbox.
5. Click "OK" and your laptop will automatically restart.

Retry Intel HAXM Installation

After completing the above steps, try installing Intel HAXM again. It should work without issues. If you encounter any errors during the installation process, make sure you have administrative privileges and that your antivirus or security software isn't blocking the installation.

Remember to restart your computer after each change in settings or installation attempt.

Comment: this still did not work, I have done everything, followed every thread possible, it just wouldn't install and when I check for it on command line this is what I get [SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

Comment: The failed error 1060 indicates no existing error service. Try temporarily disabling your antivirus or security software, check for repair system files, run commands as an administrator, remember to restart your computer after making changes to ensure that they take effect, and check for possible window updates. Hope this will help.