# Facing Android Studio Emulator Error with AMD CPU [2021]

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator, processor, amd-processor

You open Android Studio as always, but if you would like to run an emulator device one of the following error appear:

> Unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD
> Processors

or

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
> Android Emulator Hypervisor
> Driver for AMD Processor is not installed.

or later in cmd or Powershell

> [SC] DeleteService succeed. Fail of [SC] StartService error 4294967201

Comment: While this is quite a nice post (as far as I can tell; I don't have domain knowledge to verify it), the title is lacking. For the sake of searchability, the title should describe the problem. Thank you for cleanly contributing to the site though.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! :) I try my best. I changed the title to clarify the specific problem. Have a nice day buddy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**INTRODUCTION**

First of all, I know that there are some posts out there. But there not up to date or incomplete.
I want to point that my intention with this post is to make a nearly 100% working knowledge base for this issue. Serving as a step by step tutorial for fixing that problem properly.

Don't panic, we will fix that now :)

**CHECK-1:**

Check your BIOS Settings first. Virtualization Technology needs to be enabled in BIOS.
Gigabyte, Asus Rog or MSI for example call that SVM Mode ("Secure Virtual Machine") other may call that as mentioned: "Virtualization"

`F2`/`Del` to access `BIOS` -> `Advanced Settings` -> `CPU Configuration` -> `SVM Mode` -> `Enable`, safe that with `F10` (Asus BIOS Example)

[image: BIOS Enable SVM Mode]

As BIOS options are different among vendors, please refer to your system manufacturer's manual.

**CHECK-2:**

Type in your Windows searchbar (Lower left corner) "`Windows Features`".
Make sure Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform are disabled. All Windows features enabling Hyper-V either explicitly or silently must be turned off. Restart your computer after. See the screenshots below for what you need to uncheck:

[image: Uncheck the arrow marked fields]

Note that in a future Studio 4.0 release, these instructions will be automatically run as part of the SDK Manager update and become obsolete.

**CHECK-3:**

To really ensure that Hyper-V is disabled run following command in `Powershell`.
Open powershell: Right click on your Windows Logo (Lower left corner) -> click `Windows Powershell (Administrator)` -> proceed with following command:

> Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V

**SETUP ANDROID STUDIO**

We now want to install the missing Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors:
In Android Studio navigate `File` -> `Settings` -> expand `Appearance & Behavior` -> expand `System Settings` -> `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools` -> install `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)` -> `Apply` -> `OK`

[image: Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)]

**RUN THE INSTALLER**

Now you downloaded the package of the driver you need to find it's location.
In the image below you see the path of your Android SDK's.

[image: Android SDK Location]

Copy that path into your Explorer and navigate through like in image below to your `silent_install.bat`

[image: Navigate to your silent_install.bat]

Copy the complete path of your explorer and run `Powershell` as Administrator (how to open, explained above). In `Powershell` type:

> cd [here your copied path]

Afterwards execute your installer by typing:

> .\silent_install.bat

You will probably get an error, but that isn't important, because the installer worked. We will see it later. The service only couldn't start because one of our **3 CHECKS** above are not done properly.
Then it will look something like that:

[image: Installer executed]

We use this "worst case" to proof that the installer operated sucessfully even with the following errors.

> [SC] DeleteService succeed. Fail of [SC] StartService error 4294967201

[image: StartService error 4294967201]

They may lead you to a github directory. To download a code there, but it isn't necessary at all. It worked already. Let's try it out.

PS: If everything went as it should it will look like that (Best case):

[image: Best Case, everything appears right but it doesn't need to]

**CREATING EMULATOR DEVICE**

Let's create an android device and test it. I made it step by step as shown in the screenshots:

[image: Window 1 and 2]

After you selected a device you are finally able to download the android version of the device:

[image: Window 3]

Make your unique settings:

[image: Window 4]

Run your device:

[image: Window 5]

**FINAL & CONCLUSION**

Now you are able to work with the `android studio emulator` and an AMD Processor. Congratz! :)
I know it was a long tutorial, but you made it trough.
If you face any issues, comment below, I try to help you!
That was it once again from my side. I keep this post updated.

[image: It worked! Wuhuu :)]

Comment: OMG Thank YOU!!!!11 ---- I have followed so many random stackoverflow posts some saying to enable Hyper-V some saying to disable it, but your specific combination of disabling hyper V with the online command, then installing the AMD package with silent install worked perfectly. I literally haven't been able to launch AVDs for months now until I read your answer 

Comment: Men I really have to write a THANK YOU!!!!! I tried 50000 stackoverflow answers from (antivirus,hyper-v,secureboot,device integrity and other stuff) only yours worked

Comment: @Ojav glad that it worked :) I was trying a lot to reproduce the error and to find out this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, had issues on a AMD ryzen 2600x. In the Bios under MIT setting and advanced memory frequency I found the setting for virtulization to enable it.

Comment: not just that bro.