# Android Studio Emulator Disconnecting

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, hyper-v

I'm running `Android Studio 4.1.1` on `Windows 10 Pro` with `Hyper-V` disabled.
I just upgraded to `Emulator 30.5.4` and `HAMX 7.6.5`. Now when I try to
run the Emulator it disconnects on start up. Has anyone else run into something
similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try my [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932346/facing-android-studio-emulator-error-with-amd-cpu-2021/66932347#66932347) I wrote to setup your Emulator properly for an AMD CPU (Seems you have one).

For Intel you need to Uncheck the `Use Host GPU` checkbox - in the emulator settings. And also disable your `Hyper-V` in `Windows Feature Settings`
PS: If you use HP SureClick - remove it.

I keep that post updated, like all my posts, to ensure a complete solution. :)

Comment: I'm actually running on an Intel i5-10600 CPU and using Intel Processsor ID Utility to be sure VT is enabled. Do you have a similar document for an Intel CPU? Thank you!!!

Comment: I added something you can try in my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The problem was HP SureClick. Once I removed it, the emulator started working again. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad that it helped normaly the metioned solution for intel helps. I add your answer to mine. You can tick it right or not. Up to you. Cheers and Happy Coding! :)