# Cant install Intel HAXM via Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, emulation, intel, haxm

I've tried to install/run Intel HAXM via Android Studio but I'm getting a persistent error with it failing to run as "the system cannot find the batch label specified - in_exit9009". I've tried installing HAXM via Android Studio and downloading the installer itself from Intel, but still no luck. Below is the screenshot of the issue.

It seems like the issue might be due to my user profile having a space between it, but if so, how do I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: have a look at this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162833/12830957)

Answer (score 0):

Find out if the next options could work for you:

1st

- restart and go to BIOS > advanced > enable virtualizations
- save and restart
- try installing HAXM again

2nd

- from control panel > programs and features > turn windows features on or off
- uncheck Hyper-v
- uncheck windows sandbox
- ok
- try installing HAXM again